Question on countability of set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
This question appeared on a math test at my school (I am paraphrasing):
Tyler wants to prove that the set $F=\{f:f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\}$ (set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$) is countable. Where is the first mistake in his proof?
L1: It suffices to find a bijection from F to $\mathbb{N}$.
L2: Define the function $g:F\to\mathbb{N}$ given by: $g(f)=2^{f(1)}3^{f(2)}5^{f(3)}\dots p_{i}^{f(i)}\dots$ where $p_{i}$ is the i-th prime.
L3: Since every number greater than 2 has a prime factorization, g is surjective.
L4: Since the prime factorization of every number greater than 2 is unique, g is injective.
L5: Since g is injective and surjective, it is bijective. We conclude that $|F|=|\mathbb{N}|$.
I believe that the FIRST mistake is in line 2, since for most functions $f$, $g(f)$ will be unbounded and thus not a natural number so it is ill defined from $F\to\mathbb{N}$.
For example, the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ given by $f(x)=1$ has $g(f)=2\times3\times5\times7\dots$ which is not bounded and therefore is not a natural number, since it is larger than any natural number.
I do not believe the argument that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under multiplication holds since this is only true for multiplying exactly $2$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$, since you can only inductively prove that it holds for $n$ multiplications for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. for a finite number of multiplications.
However, my friend argues that the first mistake is in line 3, since evidently any finite number in $\mathbb{N}$ is not mapped to by $g$ since every $g(f)$ is unbounded. ($f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded since every input is at least 1).

You're right, the first error is in L2: That doesn't define a function.


L2: Define the function $g:F\to\mathbb{N}$ given by: $g(f)=2^{f(1)}3^{f(2)}5^{f(3)}\dots p_{i}^{f(i)}\dots$ where $p_{i}$ is the i-th prime.

It already fails here. Say $f(x)=1$. Then what is $g(f)$ supposed to be?
In fact this only works for those functions that are eventually zero. Because then we can simply ignore multiplications by $p_i^0=1$. And indeed the number of such functions is countable. And indeed, $g$ is surjective for such functions, even bijective, which does follow from the prime factorization theorem.

I believe that the FIRST mistake is in line 2, since for most functions $f$, $g(f)$ will be unbounded and thus not a natural number so it is ill defined from $F\to\mathbb{N}$.

You are somewhat on the right track. But technically $g(f)$ is not unbounded. The term "unbounded" applies to functions, or maybe sets. But $g(f)$ is neither. In fact $g(f)$ is not anything, it simply is not well defined: we don't have a notion of infinite product of numbers. Not in this context anyway. The only way for that definition to work is when $f(i)=0$ eventually.

To add on to the end: In fact, this proof establishes that there are countably many functions which are 0 eventually.  (Invoking Schroder Bernstein to deal with the pesky pre-image of 1.)

You are correct in that there is a catastrophic error is in I.2, in fact $g(f)$ as constructed is not finite even given that $f$ is bounded.
RE I.3: You do not need $g$ to be surjective. More precisely, to show that a set $G$ is countable, all you need is an injective map $g': G \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. All you need, in particular here,  is $f \not = f' \implies g(f) \not = g(f')$ and $g(f)$ and $g(f')$ in $\mathbb{N}$. You do not have that however, as I.2 is not correct.
